# How to distribute WinHlp for Win 7 installations?

Tags: windows-installer, redistributable

This article indicates that `.HLP` files will not load on Windows Vista and later unless `Update KB917607` is installed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917607

How can this update be distributed in an `MSI` based installation?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Microsoft does not offer the rights to redistributed this update. If that's correct, regardless of the technical problems, you may not do what you propose.

As a general answer towards installing prerequisites, look for support for installing redistributables in your bootstrap. Only rarely should you consider launching another redistributable from your Windows Installer package.

Comment: What do you mean by 'bootstrap'? Are you talking about the application itself?

Comment: In this context, a bootstrap is an exe that prepares for and launches your installation package. This is in contrast with the .msi file which is just the installation package.